# Process C#| How To Make A Process Into system tray

Tags: c#

So, I have a `Process` running in C#, and I want to make it a system tray. Is it possible?

This is the code I am using:

```
Process proc = Process.Start("XXXX");
```

Comment: You do understand that would start the application on the Server right?

Comment: Hrm, are you actually trying to do this from an ASP.NET application? Because neither `Process.Start` nor `NotifyIcon` is going to be very successful in that case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is for the process to control whether it should show as a task on the taskbar, or in the notification area; As such, you couldn't control this for a process you're starting unless it documents a command line option for this purpose.

Of course, you can control this for your own WinForms applications using components such as the `NotifyIcon` component (part of the .Net framework).

Comment: +1 for knowing that it's called the 'notification area' (and having the right answer)

Comment: i didnt understand, how can i do it ?

Comment: @Alon the short version is "you can't"

Comment: Thanks!, so i cant in my own process, how can i do it on my form, any short guild?:)